# WinRT inhibit "Immersive Application Domain): Loaded ..." messages in Output Window

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, debugging, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When i run my XAML c# **windows store app** in Visual Studio I see **many messages** similar to :

```
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

**How do I stop these messages appearing?**

As I'd like a clearer output window and can concentrate on the important bits such as :

```
Debug.Writeline("my own messages");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio :

Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window

Set the **"Module Load Messages"** option to **"Off"**